# Widget same size as it's children?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, resize, widget

In Qt, how can I have a widget which automatically sizes itself according to the size of it's children?

For example, if I have a `QGroupBox` which contains a `QHBoxLayout` which contains some `QPushButton`s, I would like the `QGroupBox` to automatically calculate it's size so that it is no bigger and no smaller than necessary to fit all of the `QPushButton`s.

Ideally I would like to be able to do this in Qt Designer so that I can create a `.ui` file which already knows how to size the `QGroupBox`, however I am also opening to deriving from a class inside a `.ui` file and doing the resizing manually.

I have tried placing the `QGroupBox` inside it's own layout (with and without a spacer) but this just resizes the `QGroupBox` to the smallest possible size so that none of the children are visible.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to pay attention to:

1. Set the size policies appropriately on the children in the groupbox. You literally need to think what the buttons can do - most likely, you do not want the buttons to either grow or shrink, so setting both of their size policies to `Fixed` is the right thing to do. You could, possibly, let the buttons expand horizontally, so the horizontal policy of `MinimumExpanding` is an option.
2. Set the size constraint on the layout in the groupbox to act according to your objective:

   ```
   ui->groupbox->layout()->setConstraint(QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize);
   ```

Of course, the groupbox will be inside of *some* layout in its parent window, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: I have already done (1). I'm unclear on (2) - the problem is that I want the groupbox to figure out it's own min and max sizes based on its children. Your example seems to imply that I've already specified the sizes for the groupbox, unless I'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have the most luck by sub classing QGroupBox and overriding sizeHint or other sizing functions to loop through children and calculate the minimum bounding rectangle.  Depending on how dynamic the group box is, managing connections to new widgets might be a small challenge.